# C# ChatBot switching between dialogs smoothly

Tags: c#, .net-core, dialog, botframework, chatbot

I'm developing a ChatBot using different dialogs. The conversation starts in a MainDialog and then branches depending on the user's necessity.
So let's say the Dialog branches are `TechnicalSupport` and `ProductInformation`.

If a user is currently asking for a `TechnicalSupport` related question but in the middle of the conversation wants to know something about some product, is there a way so that the `ProductInformation` dialog captures the message, sends a quick response and then resume the state of the `TechnicalSupport` conversation flow?

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a way. You can follow [this](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/13.core-bot/Dialogs/CancelAndHelpDialog.cs) sample and add an interruption for your product. You should follow the "help" interruption as it resumes the dialog after sending a message unlike the "cancel" which totally end your current dialog. It can be triggered by text or LUIS intent.

```
 private async Task<DialogTurnResult> InterruptAsync(DialogContext innerDc, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        if (innerDc.Context.Activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Message)
        {
            var text = innerDc.Context.Activity.Text.ToLowerInvariant();

            switch (text)
            {
                case "help":
                case "?":
                    var helpMessage = MessageFactory.Text(HelpMsgText, HelpMsgText, InputHints.ExpectingInput);
                    await innerDc.Context.SendActivityAsync(helpMessage, cancellationToken);
                    return new DialogTurnResult(DialogTurnStatus.Waiting);

                case "cancel":
                case "quit":
                    var cancelMessage = MessageFactory.Text(CancelMsgText, CancelMsgText, InputHints.IgnoringInput);
                    await innerDc.Context.SendActivityAsync(cancelMessage, cancellationToken);
                    return await innerDc.CancelAllDialogsAsync(cancellationToken);
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
```